# How to pass data from one android activity to an Java class?

Tags: java, android, class, android-intent

**MainActivity(Activity)**

```
String emailid=e1.getText().toString();
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,LongOperation.class);
i.putExtra("emailid",emailid);
```

**LongOperation(Java class )**

```
Intent i = getIntent();
a = i.getStringExtra("emailid");
```

**ERROR MESSAGE:**

> 'getIntent(java.lang.String)' is deprecated as of API 15: Android
> 4.0.3 (IceCreamSandwich)

Comment: `LongOperation` is it an `activity` or `service` or what?

Answer (score 0):

In **1st Class**:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LongOperation.class);
                    i.putExtra("emailid", emailid);
                    startActivity(i);
```

In **2nd Class**:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
   String emailid= i.getStringExtra("emailid");
```

Answer (score -2):

Intents are used to pass data from one activity to another activity.

So if you want to pass data to a normal Java class i would suggest you to use a getter function in combination with a static java class.

So LongOperation has to look like that:

```
public class LongOperation {
    private static String eMailID;

    // gives the variable eMailID in this class the new value mailID
    public static void setMailID(String mailID) {
        eMailID = mailID;
    }

    // add additional code here
}
```

In the MainActivity you have to do sth like:

```
String emailid = e1.getText().toString();
// set the variable in the LongOperation class
LongOperation.setMailID(emailid);
```

I hope I got your question right, there are several other ways but that depends on the structure and logic of your code.
In general I would recommend to work not so much witch static, more object orientated. But in this case static might be easier.
Cheers